# Why does bcmul return a number with a scale different than the one I specified?

Tags: php, bcmath

I can't seem to find anything in the php.net documentation that explains the following results:

```
$ php -r 'var_dump(bcsub("0.3", "0.2", 4));'
string(6) "0.1000"
$ php -r 'var_dump(bcmul("0.3", "0.2", 4));'
string(4) "0.06"
```

The subtraction result is exactly what I would expect it to be (I specified a 4-digit scale, and it gave me one in the result).  The multiplication result does not (I specified a 4-digit scale, but it gave me a 2-digit one in the result).  Why the difference?

**Note:**  I already know how to use [`number_format()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php), and I also know that `0.06 === 0.0600` mathematically.  I'm only interested in understanding why BC Math seems to act differently with respect to the scale of the result.

**Note #2:**  As mentioned above, `number_format()` is not an answer to this question, and the answers used in the referenced "duplicate question" all advise using `number_format()`.  I know full well that this function can be used to format the number to the specified precision.  I'm just curious to know **WHY** the return values for these functions have different scales, **NOT** how to fix them so that they do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a bug in PHP's BCMath function `bcmul`. It's still present as of PHP 5.5.7, the latest stable release as of this writing.

If you [browse the source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/PHP-5.5/ext/bcmath/libbcmath/src) (PHP 5.5's BCMath recmul.c), you'll see the relevant function:

```
void
bc_multiply (bc_num n1, bc_num n2, bc_num *prod, int scale TSRMLS_DC)
{
  bc_num pval; 
  int len1, len2;
  int full_scale, prod_scale;

  /* Initialize things. */
  len1 = n1->n_len + n1->n_scale;
  len2 = n2->n_len + n2->n_scale;
  full_scale = n1->n_scale + n2->n_scale;
  prod_scale = MIN(full_scale,MAX(scale,MAX(n1->n_scale,n2->n_scale)));

  /* Do the multiply */
  _bc_rec_mul (n1, len1, n2, len2, &pval, full_scale TSRMLS_CC);

  /* Assign to prod and clean up the number. */
  pval->n_sign = ( n1->n_sign == n2->n_sign ? PLUS : MINUS );
  pval->n_value = pval->n_ptr;
  pval->n_len = len2 + len1 + 1 - full_scale;
  pval->n_scale = prod_scale;
  _bc_rm_leading_zeros (pval);
  if (bc_is_zero (pval TSRMLS_CC))
    pval->n_sign = PLUS;
  bc_free_num (prod);
  *prod = pval;
}
```

Note: The word "scale" refers to the number of digits after the separator.

Take a look at the line where `prod_scale` is assigned.  When you invoke `bcmul("0.3", "0.2", 4)`, walking through the code, we see: `prod_scale = MIN(2,MAX(4,MAX(1,1)));`, so `prod_scale` is assigned a value of `2`.

And, as expected, the function returns a value with two, not four, digits after the decimal place. Unlike in the other BCMath PHP functions (e.g., see lines 63-98 of PHP 5.5's BCMath [doaddsub.c](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/94e15ff3877f842e5eb5c89e3aeab214fb4a3a33/ext/bcmath/libbcmath/src/doaddsub.c)), nowhere in this function's logic does it append the trailing zeros.

---

I've submitted this issue and a patch to the PHP bug tracking system ([#66364](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66364)).